# Typescript library not publish as npm package how to import type file *d.ts to another project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am studying using webpack to build library.

In webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    filename: 'mylib.js',
    library: {
        name: 'mylib',
        type: 'umd'
    },
    globalObject: 'this',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

In tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
"module": "es6",
"outDir": "./dist",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": true,
"moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

My output result is like below:

[image]

The output mylib.js to use in another typescript project, and

```
import * as mylib from './libs/mylib';
```

There is warning of 'Could not file a declaration file for module mylib.js'. I know that it is not found corresponding *.d.ts files.

But i have no idea of how to put the corresponding *.d.ts files generated.
As I name the library file as mylib.js, how will it correlate to index.d.ts that built out?

Due to some reasons, it will not publish as npm package.

Thanks a lot.